# MAX SUM, when multiplying two values from seperate tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been able to get the total value of the two values but I'm not sure how to get the max. So when I enter this code, I have 4 row with the correct values but I just want to display the row with the maximum value out of those 4 rows.

```
SELECT AC.ACTID, SUM(AC.HOURS_WORKED * AL.HOURLYRATE) TOTAL
FROM ACTION AC
INNER JOIN ALLOCATION AL
ON AC.ACTID = AL.ACTID
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON E.EMPID = AL.EMPID
GROUP BY AC.ACTID
```

I have to also put in EMPID but I'm not worried about that because that part is fine. Also this is SQL code.

Comment: One way is to order your results descending and only keep the top row. What DBMS are you using? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question. In this case for instance the solution depends on it. While you get the top row with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` in standard SQL, some DBMS have a `TOP` or `LIMIT` clause instead.

Comment: You are not worried about getting the EMPID into your results? You show one result per action, and the employees and actions are m:n related. So there is not one employee ID, but several. How do you intend to solve this? Put them in a comma-separated string?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think "dad" if that's a DBMS, but we've been told to try work with MAX and SUM so that's why I haven't tried anything else

Comment: I am not aware of any DBMS called dad. Common DBMS are MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and Oracle for instance. Well, then there is that horrible MS Access of course, and there are many others. It is important to know what DBMS you are using, because SQL dialects differ. What works for one DBMS may not work for another.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am going to put EMPID into the results, I just didn't have it in that code while I was trying to do the MAX because it confused me more so I removed it for the time being

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it is Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You are showing actions with their cumulated costs.

According to your query the `action` table contains `hours_worked` and this value applies to every single employee involved. E.g. with `hours_worked = 5` and three employees on that action, there were 15 hours worked.

Then there is the `allocation` table allowing many employees to work on one action on one hand and one employee to participate on many actions on the other (m:n relation). The employees are thus grouped per action. Say, in the example of three employees, one is allocated with an `hourlyrate` of 100 and the other two are allocated with an `hourlyrate` of 200. Then you have a total of 1 * 5 * 100 + 2 * 5 * 200 = 2500.

You are selecting many actions and you only want to show the top one(s) according to the calculated totals. If you have four actions for instance with the totals 1000, 2000, 2500, and again 2500, you want to show the two actions with 2500.

In Oracle (and standard SQL for that matter), you use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` for that:

```
SELECT 
  ac.actid, 
  SUM(ac.hours_worked * al.hourlyrate) AS total
FROM action ac
INNER JOIN allocation al ON ac.actid = al.actid
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.empid = al.empid
GROUP BY ac.actid
ORDER BY total DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

As there are multiple employees involved per action, you'll have to create a string with their list, if you want to show them with the action. Use `LISTAGG` for this.